# Convert String saved in database to component angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I have a div with where I add Dynamically my components

and then I save this component in server side into my database to store updates done on my DIV

I take html code from my Div and put it in database

then I need to recover this html code (as string) from database to continue my updating on my div

but when I append my html code to my div is not considered as a component angular2

so how to convert string or html code to component angular2

thanks

```
var component = new (<Type>Function)();
var annotations = [
    new Component({
        selector: "foo"
    }),
    new View({
        template: text,
        directives: [WordDirective]
    })
];

// I know this will not work everywhere
Reflect.defineMetadata("annotations", annotations, component);

// compile the component
this.compiler.compileInHost(<Type>component).then((protoViewRef: ProtoViewRef) => {
    this.viewContainer.createHostView(protoViewRef);
});
```

Comment: This might be interesting to you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7596 (also the linked StackOverflow question)

Comment: I update my question could you explain the code I added pleaasse

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I just remember the discussion and haven't seen any other solution/workaround yet.